# Boxplot for different length of serial values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a csv file like below :[image]

With different length of the values for each column. Trying to plot as a boxplot.

[image]

**code**:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.read_csv('/content/filename.csv', sep=';')
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

plt.plot()
plt.boxplot([df.dc_class0,df.dc_class1, df.dc_class3, df.dc_class2, df.dc_class4,            df.dc_class5, df.dc_class6, df.dc_class7, df.dc_class8, df.dc_class9, df.dc_class10,   df.dc_class11], 
        labels=['M0 '+str(round(df.dc_class0.mean(),1)),
                'M1 '+str(round(df.dc_class1.mean(),2)),
                'M2 '+str(round(df.dc_class2.mean(),3)), 
                'M3 '+str(round(df.dc_class3.mean(),4)), 
                'M4 ' +str(round(df.dc_class4.mean(),3)),
                'M5 ' +str(round(df.dc_class5.mean(),3)),
                'M6 ' +str(round(df.dc_class6.mean(),3)),
                'M7 ' +str(round(df.dc_class7.mean(),3)),
                'M8 ' +str(round(df.dc_class8.mean(),3)),
                'M9 ' +str(round(df.dc_class9.mean(),3)),
                'M10 ' +str(round(df.dc_class10.mean(),3)),
                'M11 ' +str(round(df.dc_class11.mean(),3)),

                ])

plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.title('Dices des différentes classes')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I didn't get plots for the column 5,6,7 and 8, idk where is the problem, is there any other method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is missing data in `df.dc_class5`, `df.dc_class6`, `df.dc_class7`, `df.dc_class8`, which still stop the boxplot from showing up for these columns. You can use the `.dropna()` method for each of the columns with `NaN` when calling `plt.boxplot`.

Also I think you switched df.dc_class2 and df.dc_class3 accidentally.

```
plt.boxplot([
    df.dc_class0, df.dc_class1, df.dc_class2, 
    df.dc_class3, df.dc_class4, 
    df.dc_class5.dropna(), df.dc_class6.dropna(),
    df.dc_class7.dropna(), df.dc_class8.dropna(), 
    df.dc_class9, df.dc_class10, df.dc_class11
    ], 
        labels=[
            'M0 '+str(round(df.dc_class0.mean(),1)),
            'M1 '+str(round(df.dc_class1.mean(),2)),
            'M2 '+str(round(df.dc_class2.mean(),3)), 
            'M3 '+str(round(df.dc_class3.mean(),4)), 
            'M4 ' +str(round(df.dc_class4.mean(),3)),
            'M5 ' +str(round(df.dc_class5.mean(),3)),
            'M6 ' +str(round(df.dc_class6.mean(),3)),
            'M7 ' +str(round(df.dc_class7.mean(),3)),
            'M8 ' +str(round(df.dc_class8.mean(),3)),
            'M9 ' +str(round(df.dc_class9.mean(),3)),
            'M10 ' +str(round(df.dc_class10.mean(),3)),
            'M11 ' +str(round(df.dc_class11.mean(),3)),

        ]
    )
```